# Not calling [super dealloc] inside a static UIViewController subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, static, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

In my app I have a UIViewController subclass (VC for short) that I only use in one place in the entire app. In that place, I have been creating and pushing it like this:

```
MyViewController* VC = [MyViewController new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
[VC release];
```

but I was thinking that since this is the only place I am using a view controller of this type, I could do something like this so the settings used won't be reset each time the view controller is pushed onto the stack:

```
static MapsToSendPicker* VC = nil; 
if(!VC) {
    VC = [MapsToSendPicker new];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
[VC release];
```

The problem with that code is that in VC's `dealloc` method, I release all of my instance variables and set them to nil, and finally I call `[super dealloc]`. This deallocates the static view controller, but the test `if(!VC)` isn't evaluated to true after (this would defeat the purpose of the whole idea if it were; then I'd have to recreate the view controller each time anyway).

My solution is overriding the `dealloc` method in MyViewController and *not* calling `[super dealloc]` at the end. This works, but the compiler raises a warning. How can I get rid of that warning while maintaining the functionality I gain with this design? Thanks!

Edit:

After a quick Google search, I have found this solution:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    if(NO) {
        [super dealloc];
    }
}
```

but I would like something a little bit... cleaner. Any thoughts?

Comment: After a quick google search you found the **completely wrong answer**.  That "solution" is a memory leak at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `[VC release];` line and add [super dealloc] back. Everything will work properly and dealloc will never get called. Generally you should consider using `NSUserDefaults` in order to restore the VC properties instead of keeping the controller in memory all the time.